# jQuery Mobile Phonegap generate installation number (unique)

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova, mobile

We are using jquery mobile and phonepag build to develop a mobile application using HTML5 to be worked on IOS and Adroid platforms. The question is how proceed to get/ generate new number (unique) not UUID, when install the application on the device, i.e. when the installation of the app is done, a generated unique number is set and saved into the database, and we want to be able to get that number (value) in every time we launch the app. This process has for role to get the count of users installed the app (number of installations) and specify or identify an user instead of UUID.

Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: What's wrong with: var string = device.uuid;.?

Comment: Not reliable and not unique!

Comment: But can be used with concatenation with appid, i.e.: appid_uuid.